# Kartik export menu showing incompatible error message

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using kartik export menu and it's showing the error below.

> PHP Strict Warning – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> kartik\grid\GridView and kartik\base\BootstrapTrait define the same property ($bsVersion) in the composition of kartik\grid\GridView. This might be incompatible, to improve maintainability consider using accessor methods in traits instead. Class was composed

Code:

```
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

<?php 
    $gridColumns = [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        'bi',
        'num_movel',
        'nome_cliente',
        // 'user_criacao',
        'data_criacao',

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ];
?>

<div class="export-menu">
    <?php echo ExportMenu::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'columns' => $gridColumns
    ]); ?>
</div>
<div class="c"></div>
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
]); ?>
```

What can be the cause of this since i've followed the kartik instructions for using the export menu?

Comment: I got a similar message with X-Tabs and Base the other day after a composer update. Turns out v1.9.4 of Base broke something. Have a look in packagist and try to force the second newest version of the extensions and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with kartik-v: yii2-grid 3.1.9 and yii2-export 1.3.0 recent releases.
To solve this issue you have two options:

1. Upgrade to PHP 7.X
2. Set in composer.json the specific release that is compatible with PHP 5.6.x or 5.7.x.

> composer.json

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "1.9.3",
    "kartik-v/yii2-export": "1.2.9",
    "kartik-v/yii2-grid": "3.1.8",
    "kartik-v/yii2-widget-activeform": "1.5.1",
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time solving this problem. My issue was version difference between PHP web (7.2) and PHP CLI (5.4).
Everything was solved when I executed composer using specified PHP version.

```
/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/composer update
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have a mix of manual install and composer install. Quick fix would be to re-run

**sudo composer require kartik-v/yii2-export "dev-master"**

yii-2-export can be replaced by a specific widget throwing this error e.g. GridView